# After several days of running Emacs becomes slower

Tags: emacs, emacs24

**Environment:** Win7::x64/Emacs24.2.50.1-mingw, 3 opened frames, ~10-20 opened buffers with code (no smart autocompletion/etags/etc) and dired buffers (~ 50% / 50%). Average memory consumption ~25-50Mb. No extra packages from MELPA (or similar) loaded.

When Emacs is not closed for several days (mostly that happens after 3 days), Emacs does not follow my input from a keyboard: everything what was typed in is shown with an annoying delay. Switching between buffers has also a noticeable delay.

What I tried during the slow responsiveness of Emacs:

- Killed all buffers
- `M-x` `garbage-collect`

  But these did not work for me. The only way is to restart the application again. The memory consumption is still the same.

Are there any ideas/best-practices how to prevent such issues? Possibly unload and load again all packages? Or something else?

Thanks!

Comment: Not really a programming problem in the current form. Better for Super User?

Comment: Two comments: (1) Did you start emacs using `emacs -Q` or with an init file?  If with an init file then bisect it recursively until you find what code you're using causes the problem. (2) You are using an old development snapshot of Emacs.  Consider upgrading to Emacs 24.3 (the latest release).

Comment: My guess is that it *is* a programming problem: that some code in the init file is causing problems. But I agree that at this point we cannot tell -- it might just be a bad Emacs development snapshot. Since we do not yet see code to consider, yes, it should probably be moved to Super User.

Comment: I start it with my `~/.emacs`. Otherwise I would not be able to use Emacs for my daily tasks; that's why I have not tried to bisect the problem. I just thought that there are standard ways to force garbage collecting etc. Since I the way to bisect does not fit me (it happens each 3 day; very long period for kind debugging) at all,  I am to continue using Emacs in the current state and will delete the question a bit later :)

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using Emacs 24.X, I suggest you to execute `profiler-start` once your instance becomes so slow.  Use mode cpu.  Use emacs for some seconds and type M-x `profiler-report` and look at the results.

With luck, you will find the "culprit".  If that does not help, and bisecting is expensive because of the "three days" wait, I would follow @Drew advice of upgrading to a newer non snapshot of Emacs

Comment: And if the problem is still present with a recent Emacs snapshot, I suggest you `M-x report-emacs-bug`.  These things tend to be hard to track down, but they are very important.